# carbon steel corrosion in chloride solution

Tags: corrosion

we have a alkaline solution with Cl content of 3500 ppm, and pH=10 ,my question is if the carbon steel material is proper for this solution or not?

Comment: Here's a source for some basic information that might help:
https://marinecorrosionforum.co.uk/resources

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how long you want it to last to decide if it is "proper". Generally the solution sounds like seawater ( although seawater pH is around 8 +).Corrosion will be strongly affected by factors not presented: oxygen, velocity, temperature, etc.As a wild guess a corrosion rate of one millimeter per year is possible.